# OpenFileDialog causes Exception when clicking "New Folder" button or pasting files

Tags: c#, exception, access-violation, openfiledialog

When I debug my application with Visual Studio 2013 C# (whether admin-mode or not) and use "Create new Folder"-button in the OpenFileDialog, it creates a new folder and causes either

- a SEHException, saying that an external component caused an exception
- or a System.AccessViolationException.

When I start the compiled application through explorer the exception doesn't appear.

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Works fine here. How are we to reproduce this? Could the problem be a shell extension?

Comment: You get a lot of shell extensions loaded into your process when you use that dialog.  They can misbehave in highly undiagnosable ways, an AVE is certainly a possibility.  Enabling unmanaged debugging can give you a decent clue.  But certainly best to clean-up your machine aggressively to get it stable again, use SysInternals' AutoRuns utility.

Comment: Thank you. But when I use unmanaged debugging it throws this: Exception (first Chance) at 0x77CA70CF (ntdll.dll) in TableComparer.exe: 0xC0000008: An invalid handle was specified

Comment: Also: a right mouse click on "Computer" in the OFD causes the exception.

Answer (score 2):

I guess when you are directly running the .exe it is running under your user account which has more privileges. But for direct debug it is running under VS host process which does not have elevated permissions to create folder.

So when you create the .exe make sure you run it with elevated privileges. So that you can create folders. Or catch exception and display message to user to run it as Administrator.

Comment: No, it creates the folder and afterwards it cuases the exception.

Comment: Why would the VS host process have different rights? Answer: it doesn't. And even if it did, why would a lack of rights lead to an AV? Answer it would not, it would lead to `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

Comment: Aha, can you please paste the exception text here? Including inner exception.

Comment: Source       : System.Windows.Forms
Method       : Show
Type         : System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException
Error        : Eine externe Komponente hat eine Ausnahme ausgelöst.
Stack Trace  : bei System.Windows.Forms.FileDialogNative.IFileDialog.Show(IntPtr parent)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.FileDialog.RunDialogVista(IntPtr hWndOwner)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.FileDialog.RunDialog(IntPtr hWndOwner)

Comment: Extended Stack Trace: 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LogError
Application_ThreadException
OnThreadException
WndProcException
OnThreadException
Callback
DispatchMessageW
System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop
RunMessageLoopInner
RunMessageLoop
Run
Main
_nExecuteAssembly
ExecuteAssembly
RunUsersAssembly
ThreadStart_Context
RunInternal
Run
Run
ThreadStart